# How to create a logo as same as given measurement/proportion. I have already created one. Kindly refer below

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, client-relations, measurement

**Client specification goes like this:**

"Keep in mind that for actual utilization of the logo, the size may vary from **3 cms x 3 cms to 75 x 75 cms**. While designing, this aspect should be kept in mind."

I have already created the logo in illustrator. Will I have to create that logo as given measurement/proportion or I can vary. Means my logo is rectangle in shape and client's specification (3cm x 3cm to 75cm to 75 cm) will be square in shape. I hope you understand what I mean. Kindly help.

Answer (score 4):

What your client means is that the logo you create has to be **scalable**. So you are not supposed to use raster graphics, as they would lose quality when you resize them.

Because you are using Illustrator, if you created your logo with vectorial tools (drawing your shapes, for example), that should be enough. As long as your client has access to the original file, he/she can output it in any size.

When you deliver your result to the client, make sure you send different formats of it (.eps, .svg, that are scalable, but also a high resolution .png).

Comment: Another thing to consider is that it should be fully readable/recognizable at the smallest size (3cms in this case)